# How can I fix 'ImportError: No module named 'mymodule' when installing a Python package using pip?

Tags: python

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install a Python package named 'mymodule'. I followed the standard installation process using pip, but whenever I attempt to import the module in my code, I receive the error message: "ImportError: No module named 'mymodule'."

Here's what I have already tried:

Verified that 'mymodule' is installed by running "pip show mymodule". It shows up as installed with the correct version.
Restarted my Python interpreter and even restarted my computer to ensure a clean environment.
Checked the Python version compatibility. 'mymodule' is listed as compatible with Python 3.6+ and I'm using Python 3.9.
Tried reinstalling the package using "pip uninstall mymodule" followed by "pip install mymodule" to ensure a clean installation.
Confirmed that the package is not a sub-module of another package and should be imported directly.
Despite these efforts, the import error persists. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue and successfully import the 'mymodule' package into my Python environment.